Who can "freeze UNHCR’s ability to register new refugees"?
Allegedly only half the Syrians in Lebanon are registered with the UNHCR because

The process of obtaining legal status is arduous for Syrian refugees, with only 17 percent of Syrians possessing valid residency due to Lebanon’s stringent immigration rules and a freeze on UNHCR’s ability to register new refugees since 2015.

Who can "freeze UNHCR’s ability to register new refugees" in some country? How does that work exactly?

Any research been done? Maybe the UNHCR has a website that says something or there might be a Wikipedia page about it.

According to the UNHCR, the government of Lebanon did it. The UNHCR cannot override national immigration policies.

Sure, I agree with the last sentence, but how does Lebanon control whom of the people already in Lebanon UNHCR registers or not? Can you give a quote from that page that explains how that works, and where Lebanon's government can intervene/veto?

@IVFcomesfromthetip, the link I provided, scroll down to the situation analysis.

Yeah, I found where it says "suspension of UNHCR new registrations of Syrians by the Government of Lebanon in 2015". I'm still not sure how that works. I guess Lebanon can deport UNHCR staff if they don't comply with their say-so?

@IVFcomesfromthetip, among other things. That's why it is called a government.

@IVFcomesfromthetip the usual term in this context would be "expel" rather than deport, but yes, ultimately the government of Lebanon can expel any or all staff members (except for those who are Lebanese citizens or otherwise have a right to remain under Lebanese law), and the government of Lebanon can also demand that UNHCR as an organization cease all its activities in Lebanon. In fact, any government can do this, so UNHCR (and organizations like it) have to be very careful not to antagonize their host governments. Such is the nature of diplomacy.  The UN has no authority over its members.

@IVFcomesfromthetip As a side example, UNRWA (which covers Palestinian refugees in areas not under UNHCR) original mandate actually includes Jewish and Arab refugees in Israel until Israel assumes responsibility for the refugees in their country, and UNRWA no longer operates in Israel.

Apparently the government told UNHCR to stop doing it, and UNHCR complied.
How they might have threatened/elicited compliance transpires from a later, 2018 incident:

For the first time, Lebanese government officials confronted the United Nations High Commissioner for Refugees (UNHCR) over its policy on the repatriation of Syrian refugees. On June 8, the Lebanese Foreign Minister Gibran Bassil ordered a freeze on the renewal of residency permits for UNHCR staff, accusing the UN agency of discouraging Syrian refugees in Lebanon from returning to Syria.
[...] The incident that triggered the recent escalation with UNHCR relates to a group of 3,000 Syrian refugees living in the Lebanese town of Arsal who intended to return to Syria. The refugees were interviewed by UNHCR staff, as part of standard procedures, about the conditions they might face in their country, including the possibility of them facing military conscription, other security problems, and poor accommodation, which the Lebanese Foreign Minister saw as a procedure that aims at deterring refugees.
Almost one million Syrian refugees are currently registered with UNHCR in Lebanon, with estimates closer to 1.5 million. UNHCR suspended registration of incoming Syrian refugees in May 2015, according to instructions by the Lebanese government.


I found more details about the registation dispute itself on a law blog:

An essentially contested concept for the Lebanese authorities is the one of refugee. In June 2012, Lebanon’s caretaker government established a policy of neutrality towards the events in Syria, of which one strand was the enforcement of the term ‘displaced persons’ rather than ‘refugees.’ [...]
In the early stages of its Syria operation in Lebanon, UNHCR had agreed to avoid using the term refugee but, as UNHCR’s response grew more conventional, it increasingly insisted on the importance of using refugee terminology – much to the ire of the Lebanese government. The wording in the LCRP and the partnership document is thus an example not only of the contentious nature of terminology, but also of an attempt to reconcile conflicting humanitarian and state views.
The UN’s usage of the term ‘refugee movement’ is also worth noting. UNHCR has not made any official declaration of prima facie refugee status for Syrians. Prima facie refugee status is normally recognized on the basis of readily apparent, objective circumstances in the country of origin and is commonly used in mass influx situations around the world. In the Syrian case, however, UNHCR characterizes the flight of civilians from Syria equivocally, referring to it as a ‘refugee movement.’  [...]
Following the formation of a new government in September 2014, Lebanon’s Council of Ministers adopted its first clear policy on Syrian displacement known as the October Policy. This policy had one explicit goal; to decrease the number of Syrians in Lebanon by reducing access to territory and to encourage return to Syria.
The border regulations that accompanied the so-called October Policy effectively restrict admission to Lebanon for Syrians to those who can prove that their stay in Lebanon fits into one of the approved entry categories, such as tourism, business, study, or medical treatment. Importantly, the policy was followed by the implementation of two primary options for Syrian nationals to obtain residency: sponsorship by a Lebanese citizen or reliance on a UNHCR registration certificate. In other words, a Syrian can be lawfully staying in Lebanon if she or he is an economic migrant under the sponsorship system or is registered as a refugee with UNHCR.

So, the move to suspend UNHCR registration was also because it was tied to granting some rights in the eyes of the Lebanese law. But somewhat stangely, that came after the freeze/suspension, although perhaps the Lebanese government was anticipating it:

Registration procedures are a fundamental component of international protection in the Lebanese context. Notably, in 2013 and 2014, UNHCR registered on average 47,000 Syrian refugees per month in Lebanon. However, in an attempt to reduce the official number of refugees in the country – which by March 2015 had grown to almost 1,200,000 – in May 2015, the Lebanese government suspended UNHCR’s registration of Syrian refugees. At the time of the suspension order, the UNHCR registration certificate had limited practical value. While it entitled refugees to international protection and humanitarian assistance, it did not normally confer any formal status recognised by the Lebanese government. Not long after the Lebanese authorities suspended UNHCR registration, however, the registration certificate became crucial for many Syrians to obtain legal residency in Lebanon as this option was introduced by the so-called October Policy.

And then started the kerfuffle over the return process

UNHCR has declared that the current conditions in Syria do not allow for the assumption of a safe return, and participants of the Brussels conference also issued a declaration clearly stating that conditions in Syria are not conducive for the voluntary return in safety and dignity of refugees.
This declaration has been rejected by both Lebanon’s President and the minister for foreign affairs, who argue that it in fact aims to ‘resettle Syrians in Lebanon’. They warn that waiting until there is a political solution to the Syrian conflict before returning refugees could mean waiting in vain.

